# Reduce photo size to less than 20kb

Tags: file-size

I am trying to reduce image size to less than 20kb (Dimension 940*884 )for a eCommerce website. Using features of photoshop cs6 I am able to reduce image size to around 65kb. Below which the image gets distorted.  Wondering how to solve this, I downloaded a similar image from web of less 20kb. Saved it again via photoshop(using default setting) to only find it saved as 80kb. Am I missing any photoshop settings which is always increasing the size? Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Note: All images are jpeg.

***Change of question:*** I am unable to find my previous example. Let me give another example. I have downloaded a pic from the following link: flipkart.com/puma-pulse-5000-flex-tech-wicket-keeping-pads/p/… Now, The dimension of this pic is 252*400 and size is 32 kb. I open the same image in photoshop. Go to save for web option. Choose 100% quality, click save. The image gets saved as 48 kb. Why this increase in kbs? What should be done to avoid the increase in size and keep the kb size as good as original 32 kb!

Comment: Which "features of photoshop", which exact settings did you use? And can you give the URL of that "similar image"? 20kb for an image that size is just not reasonable unless it has large moncolored areas.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't download the thumbnail of a similar image?  The size and resolution you are talking about are near impossible to achieve in JPEG without substantial distortion.  That is an extremely, extremely small file size for the resolution of image you are talking about.

Comment: For an ecommerce website, image quality is more important than small file size. Use image small image thumbnails and link to larger versions. People have requested a larger image by clicking the thumbnail, and will be prepared to accept the extra loading time.

Comment: Your updated question is answered here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50789/why-does-simpy-saving-a-jpeg-at-100-quality-in-photoshop-increase-filesize (In short, if you need it to be tiny, you can't do 100% jpeg quality.)

Answer (score 4):

JPG is a compressed, lossy file format, but it is not magic! 940 x 885 pixles in 8-bit RGB color means that the uncompressed image is about 940 x 885 x 3 bytes = ca 2.5 megabytes. You are trying to compress this to 20 kilobytes, which means that you are looking for more than a 1000:1 compression rate. This is just not going to happen unless the image file is dead simple (which means that it can be compressed quite dramatically... and by "dead simple" i mean something like computer line graphics, not a photograph) or unless the JPG algorithm is allowed throw away massive chunks of image information (which I suppose is what you see when your image gets "distorted")

According to Wikipedia, for what that is worth, "JPEG typically achieves 10:1 compression with little perceptible loss of quality". You are asking for a hundred times more than that!

Comment: JPEG isn't at all well suited to compressing line graphics; you'll get better in terms of both quality and compression from GIF or PNG files for those.

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely deppends of the image you are trying to compress, for example, if the image is a chart or a pen drawing with few colors and big plain areas, a gif file will be ridiculously small. In other cases, PNG or JPEG can be a better solution. If you provide the image maybe someone can make a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment above about saving as gif or png.  One of the real advantages of a gif file is that you can reduce the number of colors, thus making the image more amenable to compression.

Answer (score -1):

Try saving the image via Save for Web in the File menu from Photoshop, by following the steps from above:
Adobe Photoshop

1. From the File menu, select Save for Web & Devices (just Save for Web in earlier versions).
   [image: File menu]

Select "Save for Web & Devices"

2. Select JPEG and enter a value between 50 and 60 for Quality.
   [image: Quality adjustment]

Select JPEG and enter a value of between 50 and 60 in the Quality field

3. Save

[Source:](https://www.york.ac.uk/communications/websites/content/images/saving-images/)

Comment: This is an inaccurate answer that will not achieve the desired file size.

Comment: Excuse me for trying to help

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I am unable to find my previous example. Let me give another example. I have downloaded a pic from the following link: http://www.flipkart.com/puma-pulse-5000-flex-tech-wicket-keeping-pads/p/itmdkmgv2bakjhd4?pid=PADDKMFQUD4CBZHY&icmpid=reco_pp_recoBundle__tab1_2&ppid=BATDCG2BPZMJGJMH                                                                Now, The dimension of this pic is 252*400 and size is 32 kb. I open the same image in photoshop. Go to save for web option. Choose 100% quality, click save. The iamge gets saved as 48 kb. Why this increase in kbs?